# PCL point_types.h #pragma warning

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting the following warning when attempting to compile a program that includes `point_types.h`

```
/opt/ros/groovy/include/pcl-1.6/pcl/point_types.h:56:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
```

The warning does not interfere with the build. However, so many of my files include `point_types.h`, that the build log gets polluted by multiple warnings. Is there any way to turn them off?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and ros-groovy freshly installed from binaries.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53418/pcl-point_types.h-#pragma-warning/) by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4954 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this is taken care of in later releases of pcl. For anyone who wants to suppress the warnings while compiling against pcl-1.6, this should do the trick:

```
rosbuild_add_compile_flags([name-of-target] '-Wno-unknown-pragmas')
```

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0